# Can TypeScript infer correct types in a switch block when using extends the same way I can when using unions?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript infers the type of `serverMessage` correctly as `ServerInformation` in the case below:

```
export interface IServerResponse {
    type: 'response';
    cmd: string;
}

export interface ServerError {
    type: 'error',
    errorcode: string;
    cmd?: string;
    trans_id?: string;
    data?: Object;
}

export interface ServerInformation {
    type: 'information',
    info: string;
    data?: Object;
}

export type ServerMessage = IServerResponse | ServerError | ServerInformation;

let serverMessage = message as ServerMessage;

switch (serverMessage.type) {
    case 'information':
        const information: Information = serverMessage.info; // type is inferred correctly
        break;
```

But in my mind it seems more in line with the class syntax I am using in other places to extend the different kinds of messages with an `IServerMessage` than to combine them to a `ServerMessage` type.

Can this be done? My attempt below fails.

```
export interface IServerMessage {
    type: string;
}

export interface IServerResponse extends IServerMessage {
    type: 'response';
    cmd: string;
}

export interface ServerError extends IServerMessage {
    type: 'error',
    errorcode: string;
    cmd?: string;
    trans_id?: string;
    data?: Object;
}

export interface ServerInformation extends IServerMessage {
    type: 'information',
    info: string;
    data?: Object;
}

let serverMessage: IServerMessage = message ;

switch (serverMessage.type) {
    case 'information':
        const information: Information = serverMessage.info; // type is still inferred as ServerMessage, not the more specific InformationMessage
        break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TL;DR` No, you need a union.

The reason the switch statement works in the first case is because you have a discriminated union. The switch can narrow the type of the union based on the check as the list of possible types is known and finite.

In the second case `IServerMessage` is an interface that can be implemented by any type, from anywhere. So typescript does not have an exhaustive list to narrow from and thus does not do any narrowing.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up questions if you have time: based on my example, do you think I should just skip the interface in my code or is there any value on keeping it?

Comment: @user1283776 If you have common properties I would keep it, but only for use as a base interface

Comment: Thanks! This thread has helped me understand more about what to use interfaces for and what to use types for