# Naming convention for interfaces and a unions that on first thought I would like to give the same name?

Tags: typescript

As you can see below I use both an interface, `IServerMessage`, and a discriminated union, `UServerMessage` for server messages.

- `IServerMessage` is what all ServerMessages have in common
- `UServerMessage` is a discriminated union to help TypeScript infer the correct type in switch case situations.

You can read more about how I came to have both these in this thread if you want: [Can TypeScript infer correct types in a switch block when using extends the same way I can when using unions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669356/can-typescript-infer-correct-types-in-a-switch-block-when-using-extends-the-same)

However, I have understood that both the `I` prefix for interfaces and even more so the `U` prefix for unions are unconventional.

What would be a common naming convention I could apply in this situation? I searched on this topic but came up short.

```
export interface IServerMessage {
    type: string;
}

export interface ServerResponse extends IServerMessage {
    type: 'response';
    cmd: string;
    trans_id?: string;
    data?: Object;
}

export interface ServerError extends IServerMessage {
    type: 'error',
    errorcode: string;
    cmd?: string;
    trans_id?: string;
    data?: Object;
}

export interface ServerProgress extends IServerMessage {
    type: 'progress',
    cmd: string,
    progress_value: number,
    trans_id?: string,
    data?: string;
}

export interface ServerInformation extends IServerMessage {
    type: 'information',
    info: string;
    data?: Object;
}

export type UServerMessage = ServerResponse | ServerError | ServerProgress | ServerInformation;
```

Comment: Not a question suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why would the `I` or `U` prefixes be unconvetional, tslint has by default the `I` prefix rule for interfaces

Comment: @ospfranco: This may have been the source for my belief: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/styleguide/styleguide.md#interface

Comment: Aha, I would really stick with TSLint before any other style guide :)

Comment: Thanks for the advise :) I'll check out the TSLint guidelines.